# CSS: make div height fit parent div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a floating div have a height that fills in the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/sergep/2qPZ2/1/

The structure is as follows:

```
Parent div______________________
|    Middle child
|    Left child - float:left
|    Right child - float:right
```

The problem is that the left child has less text than the right, meaning the right increases the height of the parent div (to fit the div), but the left floating div does not follow suit.

The css looks like so:

```
.bottomcontainer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bottomleft {
  background: #346CA5;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}


.middle {
  background: #FFCE3C;
}

.bottomright {
  background: #65B237;
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

How can I make the blue `.bottomleft` class stick to the bottom of the `.bottomcontainer`? - I'm trying to make responsive, so I don't want to use actual pixel sizes!

Consequently, how do I make the text inside vertically align middle?

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:table-cell;` on the child divs, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2fmR/1/) for an example that can be extrapolated

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the question. You can fix that by adding an extra div around `.bottomleft` and `.bottomright` and display it as table / tablecells:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="bottomcontainer">
        <div class="middle">
            <h2>Intro tag line here</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="bottomleft">
                <h2>Tag line here</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomright">
                <h2>Longer tag line goes here</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div name="content" id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom {
    display: table;
}
.bottomleft {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #346CA5;
    opacity: 1.0;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottomright {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #65B237;
    opacity: 1.0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And [**updated Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/2qPZ2/3/)

<s>Delete the float, and add an absolute positioning:</s>

```
.bottomleft {
    background: #346CA5;
    opacity: 1.0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/2qPZ2/2/).

Comment: This doesn't resize the height of the left child to fit the right child :S, only sticks it to the bottom. I'm trying to make it so the height of the left child is always the same as the right child

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question, Im about to update my answer.